# PhpMyAdmin install errors

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, php-ini

I've just installed phpmyadmin on Linux Fedora 13 with PHP 5.3.3.  I get the following 2 errors:

First: I get this on the login screen:

> Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please
>   check your PHP configuration.

-The solutions I googled for this one was to yum install mcrypt and enable it in /etc/php.ini with

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
extension=php_mcrypt_filter.dll
```

Did all that, but no go.

This second one shows up when I login:

> The mbstring PHP extension was not
>   found and you seem to be using a
>   multibyte charset. Without the
>   mbstring extension phpMyAdmin is
>   unable to split strings correctly and
>   it may result in unexpected results.

Wondering a) How can I fix these and b) What do they affect?

Thanks-

Comment: If you're using Linux you might not want `.dll` modules. They usually end in `.so`.

Comment: @goreSplatter- ha, that's prob a good start...

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787403/missing-mbstring-php-extension-when-installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac for installing via macports on darwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look which resource file is being loaded by examining `$_SERVER['PHPRC']`. This value points to the directory where PHP looks for `php.ini`. I doubt that it's `/etc`.

Then install the *right* package, which is `php-mcrypt`.

Answer (score 5):

**FULL ANSWER:**

```
yum install php-mycrypt
yum install php-mbstring
```

no php.ini editing needed

Thanks to goreSplatter for shoving me in right direction

Comment: after installing you need to restart apace server

Answer (score 1):

This command solved my issue:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

Answer (score 1):

And apparently in Ubuntu installing this will fix this issue:

```
     sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

followed by

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

and restart Apache.