# Missing mbstring PHP extension when installing phpMyAdmin on Mac

Tags: installation, phpmyadmin, mbstring

[PhpMyAdmin install errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327230/phpmyadmin-install-errors)

Having some issues with installing phpMyAdmin. I would like to resolve the following issue, but don't have a clue where to start (except maybe php.ini?).

Here's the error message.

```
The mbstring PHP extension was not found and you seem to be using a multibyte charset. Without the mbstring extension phpMyAdmin is unable to split strings correctly and it may result in unexpected results.
```

And here's a related article I found on SO that was for Linux but didn't work on my Mac (OSX 10.6 with PHP updated, etc): [PhpMyAdmin install errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327230/phpmyadmin-install-errors)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like the error message says, your PHP installation lacks the mbstring extension. The Apple-provided PHP 5.3.3 in my Snow Leopard seems to have it, but many distributions bundle the extensions separately. For instance, if you use PHP from macports you need to install the php5-mbstring -package with:

```
sudo port install php5-mbstring
```

Comment: This answer worked really well since everything I had was set up with MacPorts. Thanks!

Comment: `sudo port install php5X-mbstring` where X is the installed php version minor number

Answer (score 6):

Minor note - if you have installed a different version of php (like php5.5) you must install the correct version of the mbstring package.  In my case:

```
sudo port install php55-mbstring
```

To activate, you have to have a line like this in your php.ini file:

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

Which comes from:

```
/opt/local/var/db/php55/mbstring.ini
```

(if you use the default macports install root).

Answer (score 0):

In the newest php versions the "extension_dir" path is not enabled initial.

It works with Windows and Linux, so maybe it helps also on MacOs ... :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWHqg.png)