# Composer - the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system

Tags: php, composer-php, mbstring

I've recently tried to install package through Composer, but I have got an error `the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.`
I removed semicolon from `php.ini`, but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I have it in php /ext directory.

Comment: @joci, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18849044/1252947).

Comment: What OS are you using (linux/mac/windows)? What webserver are you using (iis/nginx/apache/etc)? Have you restarted the webserver software since updating the php.ini file?

Comment: I'm using Windows with apache server(MAMP). Yes, I restarted server.

Comment: `mbstring` settings uncommented in `php.ini`?

Comment: It has own settings in php.ini ? I thought of just uncomment extension. If it has own settings I look at it.

Comment: @joci If you found the answer as a solution to your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I set the PHPRC variable and uncommented `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll` in `php.ini` and all works well.

Comment: Can you explain better what you did please?

Answer (score 255):

```sh
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

# if your are using php 7.1
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring

# if your are using php 7.2
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring

# if your are using php 7.4
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
```

Comment: This worked but I had to install the specific php version: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring`. Do a search with `apt-cache search mbstring` to see which versions are available for your system.

Comment: also `apt-get install php7.1-mbstring` works for me

Comment: If running this returns an error of `Unable to locate package php-mbstring`, try running `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: And of course, `apt-get install php7.2-mbstring`

Comment: confirmed working (sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring) on ubuntu php 7.2.24

Answer (score 23):

1. find your `php.ini`
2. make sure the directive `extension_dir=C:\path\to\server\php\ext` is set and adjust the path (set your PHP extension dir)
3. make sure the directive `extension=php_mbstring.dll` is set (uncommented)

If this doesn't work and the php_mbstring.dll file is missing, then the PHP installation of this stack is simply broken.

Comment: I reinstalled server, but nothing has changed.

Comment: That's odd. Maybe ask for support over at MAMP or simply switch the stack.. XAMPP, WPN-XM.

Comment: I finally solved it. I set PHPRC variable and uncommented zend_extension=php_opcache.dll in php.ini.

Comment: And also I installed C++ redistributable and directx. I don't know where was a problem, but it works perfect now.

Comment: In my case there was no line for the extension php_mbstring in php.ini file. So I installed it using  sudo apt-get install php7.3-mbstring. My php version is 7.3 and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 8):

For php 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

Cheers!

Comment: this do not work for me, which repo are you using?

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 it worked as above.