# Troubles installing laravel dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies, composer-php

## *Im running Windows 10.

#### I open the cmd and type:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel **project_name**
```

#### Im getting the following lines within the cmd:

```
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

but it seems that its all good and the folder structure is correct.

#### then i type the following commnad in order to download all my dependecies [vendor dir]:

```
composer install
```

#### and i am getting the following lines within the cmd:

You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning: Accessing packagist.org over http which is an insecure protocol.
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].
```

## its has never happened to me before that i cant find a solution here or at google.

Thanks.

## PS

I reinstalled php to C:/php
i extracted the php.ini file into C:/
i set the environment variables
and i also uncommented the extension

Comment: It seems like like your installation is missing `mbstring` extension. You need to install/enable that. Can you run `phpinfo()` and see if it is actually loading? This might give you some help: http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-mbstring-in-php-46.html It might be as simple as enabling it, or you may need to download/install it first. If you're using *wamp*, click on the Tray Icon, go to `PHP -> PHP Extensions` and tick `php_mbstring` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Also take a look at this thread for further help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488917/composer-the-requested-php-extension-mbstring-is-missing-from-your-system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer - the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488917/composer-the-requested-php-extension-mbstring-is-missing-from-your-system)

Comment: i use xampp when i run the phpinfo() it says mbstring: enabled

Comment: Please check that your composer is using the same PHP version. Or try explicitly run composer with that php version (if you navigate to the `bin` folder where `php` executable sits and run `php ~/composer.phar` (or whereever your `composer.phar` file sits and then the rest of your command). It is also possible that you have multiple config files - try running `phpinfo()` in your command line terminal and see if extension is enabled.

Comment: im running win 10 as mentioned the phpinfo() wont be recognized.
when im running the php ~/composer.phar inside the C:/php/bin it says could not open input file.

Comment: You will need run command `php` to go into php CLI, and then inside that you can run `phpinfo()`. It is not uncommon for CLI to have a separate config file. The default composer installation directory on Windows is `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar`. So navigating to the php/bin folder and running such command should tell you the version: `php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar -V` If that works, you can use the same to run your other composer commands.

Comment: when running the command: 




php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetuo\composer.phar -V


Im getting that:
Composer version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

## Congratulations!

Finally I found the solution.

I've uninstalled composer and i discovered i have 2 php configurations within my pc.
I've deleted the configuration that located outside the xampp folder.
Ive downloaded a new PHP extracted it into xampp folder 
(you need to change the php.ini-development file to: php.ini)
then you have to find (ctrl+f): extension_dir and modify it to your path in my case C:/xampp/php/ext
then installed composer, located the php.exe and then it said theres an issue with openssl so i modified within the php.ini file the relevant extension (simply remove the ;)
now its working just great.

## Thanks for the help