# Composer Install - requires ext-mbstring

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, cpanel, mbstring

I am trying to do a `composer install ...`, but getting an error of `requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.` I am using Apache (Cpanel) and PHP 5.6.

Below are the ways I am trying to fix the error.

1: `yum search mbstring`

```
============================================= N/S matched: mbstring =============================================
ea-php54-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php55-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php70-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php71-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
ea-php72-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
rh-php70-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
rh-php71-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
```

2: `yum install ea-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 110.4.45.120
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 110.4.45.120
 * base: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * centosplus: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * ius: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
Package ea-php56-php-mbstring-5.6.35-1.1.5.cpanel.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

It seems mbstring is installed but why I got an error when I try to composer install?

Another way (update PHP version in cPanel)

1: WHM - already set to 7.1

[image]

2: cPanel - already set to 7.1

[image]

but version in server still 5.6

[image]

Any suggestions to resolve `require ext-mbstring` error?

Comment: What does `php -m` yield? Is `mbstring` listed there? If not, you should enable that PHP extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer - the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488917/composer-the-requested-php-extension-mbstring-is-missing-from-your-system)

Comment: Solved. The package names are different. So, this post may be good to remind others to double check what they have in their server

Comment: please post the package name for the next person ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing rh can solve this issue `yum install rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64`

Please double check what you have in your server. Mine is `rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64` not `php-mbstring`

Answer (score 9):

Try installing mbstring php library with aptitude.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.1-mbstring
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to install mbstrig

```
 yum install php-mbstring
```

Once installed restart apache

```
 service httpd restart
```

Comment: ```No package php-mbstring available.```

Comment: Restarting apache has no connection to Composer, as Composer does not use Apache

Comment: composer doesn't need apache but the application itself needs apache. Then you must restart apache to enable the php extension

Comment: But the question does not mention any application that is not working, but only the installation process which does not require a running apache process after all

Comment: You guys must have some mental problems... Everytime you install an extension you MUST restart apache. Asked or not you must do it everytime. Now giving a negative note because of apache restart is just childish and non sense.

Comment: What if I'm using NGinx? Still have to restart Apache?

Comment: The question says user is running apache.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue when trying to run a build for my PHP WordPress site. I ended up updating the `composer.json` with the snippet below in the `require` section:

```
# composer.json
# ...

"require": {
  "ext-mbstring": "*", # <-- I've added this
  "ext-gd": "*",
  "php": "7.*",
  "wordpress/wordpress": "*",

  # ...

}
```

Hopefully this can become useful to others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If there are no deeper dependencies down the line, you could use a polyfill instead: edit the composer.json and replace the problem line with `"symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0"`

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/polyfill-mbstring