# Sylius instalation

Tags: php, sylius

Any ideas? :3 I have got a problem with installing sylius. I installed a lamp and composer. So that should work. Also, I tried to install curl and things like that.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for jeremykendall/php-domain-parser 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by jeremykendall/php-domain-parser[3.0.0].
    - jeremykendall/php-domain-parser 3.0.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for league/uri 4.1.1 -> satisfiable by league/uri[4.1.1].
    - league/uri 4.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for behat/behat v3.1.0 -> satisfiable by behat/behat[v3.1.0].
    - behat/behat v3.1.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - league/uri 4.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - payum/payum 1.3.2 requires league/uri ~4.0 -> satisfiable by league/uri[4.1.1].
    - Installation request for payum/payum 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by payum/payum[1.3.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
   [long .ini files list]
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer - the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488917/composer-the-requested-php-extension-mbstring-is-missing-from-your-system)

Comment: Please search for similar questions on stackoverflow before posting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.find your php.ini

2.make sure the directive extension_dir=C:\path\to\server\php\ext is set and adjust the path (set your PHP extension dir)

3.make sure the directive extension=php_mbstring.dll is set (uncommented)

If this doesn't work and the php_mbstring.dll file is missing, then the PHP installation of this stack is simply broken and you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```