# phpmyadmin - mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, apache, debian

After I installed phpmyadmin, and run it with localhost/phpmyadmin I get error:

> phpMyAdmin - Error  The mbstring extension is missing. Please check
>   your PHP configuration

When I check **php -m** console displays that mbstring is already installed.
PHP version: 7.2.4
Installed phpmyadmin via **apt-get install phpmyadmin**

In directory /etc/php I got 3 subfolders - 7.1, 7.2, 7.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin mbstring error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599406/phpmyadmin-mbstring-error)

Comment: You also need to install `mbstring` for php version 5 which is default in the system. Install as `apt-get install php4-mbstring`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install w.r.t your PHP version.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

Or you may specific php version in command

Comment: I did it already, and after restart apache2 still the same problem

Comment: Then I am sure its version issue. Maybe you are using PHP version different than connected with Mbstring ?

Comment: After restarting web server, try to print phpinfo() and there you can see which version exactly you are using, where is its ini file and is mbstring connected or not

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.26-1

In php.ini I got:
`;extension=php_mbstring.dll`
`[mbstring]
;language for internal character representation.
;This affect mb_send_mail() and ;mbstring.detect_order.
;http://php.net/mbstring.language
;mbstring.language= Japanese`

Comment: You need to uncomment `mbstring.dll` line and then restart web server.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and worked for me after checking PHP version

```
php -v
```

which gave me  :

```
PHP 7.2.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 08:07:36) ( NTS )
```

so I did

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

Thanks