# Install PhpMyadmin 4.7.2 with php 7.0 in Nginx, access denied

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, php-7

i faced this problem when i open phpmyadmin.
[image]

I was installed, php7.0, nginx, and phpmyadmin 4.7.2 (Download the file and unzip it, put in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin , granted permission 0755)

I have no problem when run the php files, i still can check my php file, just cant open the phpmyadmin. Any clues on it?

**UPDATE 1** 
After i check the log file located in `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`, and then I try this with the command  `/sbin/restorecon -R /usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin`
then it show up another error which i need to enable a mbstring.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787403/missing-mbstring-php-extension-when-installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac

Comment: @dhruvjadia How about install on a machine which run php7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35892829/3635079

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ln -s` command to link the phpmyadmin to localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: Hi, i do copied and use the command ln -s, but it appear the problem that i state above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link 
[Missing mbstring PHP extension when installing phpMyAdmin on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787403/missing-mbstring-php-extension-when-installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac), doesnt work with php7, so i use this command.

```
yum install phpp70w-mbstring
```

It works after i restart the php-fpm. 
This question is solve.